# Hourly time series

Tags: time-series

What should I do in order to apply an ARIMA model to Hourly time series below? My goal is to predict traffic volume. Thanks in advance

ID,Datetime,Traffic
0,1/2/22 7:00,105
1,1/2/22 8:00,226
2,1/2/22 9:00,264
3,1/2/22 10:00,238
4,1/2/22 11:00,219
5,1/2/22 12:00,180
6,1/2/22 13:00,135
7,1/2/22 14:00,140
8,1/2/22 15:00,62
9,1/2/22 16:00,48
10,2/2/22 7:00,82
11,2/2/22 8:00,242
12,2/2/22 9:00,254
13,2/2/22 10:00,227
14,2/2/22 11:00,212
15,2/2/22 12:00,142
16,2/2/22 13:00,155
17,2/2/22 14:00,148
18,2/2/22 15:00,77
19,2/2/22 16:00,51

I have tried many times but always get errors due to hourly dataset issues.

Comment: Hello Atanasio. StackOverflow is a site to ask programming question, do you have some code where you're trying to do this? Is there a programming language / tool you're using? If so, what have you tried? What errors are you seeing?
See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on how to ask questions.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I finally managed to solve the problem.